# Custom Html Helpers in Asp.net MVC Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have some custom Html helpers for my Asp.net MVC 3 app. In the main application they work correctly as I have put the following in my `Web.Config`:

```
<pages clientIDMode="AutoID">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
    <add namespace="WebDibaelsaMVC.Utils.HtmlHelpers" />
    <add namespace="WebDibaelsaMVC.Utils.HtmlHelpers.DTOs" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

but I have now created an area and to make my custom helpers work I have to add a using in every page where I use them. Is there a way to add the default namespaces for that area?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Razor you might need to add the reference to the `<namespaces>` section in the `~/Views/web.config` and `~/Areas/YourAreaName/Views/web.config` and not the main `~/web.config` file. Also make sure you recompile the project, open close the view, maybe even restart Visual Studio for changes to take effect (in terms of Intellisense, it will work if you run the project).

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I had added them in the main Views but not in the area.

Comment: @Carles Company, I am glad I could help.

Comment: Had this same issue with the Reactjs.NET html helper not working within an MVC area, and adding the namespace solved it.